# How spark apply "right only" join?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Here is one method that works for me:

1. use "right outer join" for two dataset
2. use "inner join" for two dataset
3. use df1.except(df2) to get my expection.
   But, is there any other method that i can use?

Comment: Just do a left join on your right dataframe? e.g 
`df=right_df.join(left_df, on="join_col", how="left")`

Comment: Could you please show an example with some data of what you expect?

Answer (score 1):

ok, i found "left_anti" method, it works for me